# Async/await code doesn't perform as expected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

From my understanding of async, such code should be non-blocking, meaning that code always gets executed no matter if certain parts of code or certain functions aren't yet done. That's why I made **longProcess()**, a simple function that can take few seconds to fully execute. However, that's not the case in my example. After **t1()**, when **longProcess()** gets called, code execution gets paused until **longProcess()** is done and then **t2()** gets executed.

So it's either the code that's faulty, or I just don't get async principle. I'd like if someone would be so kind to either correct the code or point me to some better source where I can read some more on this subject.

```
function t1(){
  console.log(Date.now() + ' from t1(); ');
}

function longProcess(){
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10000000000) {
    i += 1;
  }
  funcGetTime();
}

function t2(){
  console.log(Date.now() + ' from t2(); ');
}

function funcGetTime(){
  console.log(Date.now());
}

async function main(){
  await t1();
  await longProcess();
  await t2();
}

main();
```

Console output

```
1516123716603 from t1();
1516123727318               // from longProcess(), blocks here
1516123727320 from t2();
```

Comment: Can you make you question theory short . First para is total waste for question ?

Comment: Fair enough. My only question would be how to make that code fully non-blocking. **longProcess()** blocks the code execution in this example.

Comment: longProcess will always be blocking. The only thing you can control there is when do you want it to start blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, async functions return a promise and by declaring a function as async you allow the usage of 'await' within it. 
What 'await' does is allows you (within an async function) to get the result of resolved promises without using '.then' promise chains.

I've changed your code a little to try to explain the behaviour:

```
function t1(){
console.log(Date.now() + ' from t1(); ');
}
 function longProcess(someNumber){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
   //an async operation that will be executed after the main call stack has finished
   setTimeout(function () {
       let i = 0;
       while (i < 1000000000) {
           i += 1;
       }
       console.log(`this is ${someNumber}`);
       resolve();
   }, 0);
   })}
function t2(){
console.log(Date.now() + ' from t2(); ');
}async function main(){
//non blocking
 t1();
longProcess(0);
t2();

console.log('------');
//blocking
await longProcess(1);
t1();
longProcess(2);
t2();
console.log('HI');
}main();
```

Comment: Indeed, that works as I'd expect it. Now I think I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: So in reality, I'd still need to rely on promises in my functions, in order to use async/await properly when expecting results. Was **setTimeout(fn, 0)** necessity in this example?

Comment: async/await is mostly syntactic sugar for promises so yes.
It's worth noting that by using await instead of then you have to handle the possible errors (promise rejections) that may accrue by wrapping you code in a try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

**To make you understand . Node.js is single threaded language . If you write code which don't have I/O blocking request like database read ,  file read . the code will run in sequence. That is what your code is doing here . If you want if I/O block . I have added settimout in the below code .**

You totally misunderstood async/await in node.js.

The node.js is asynchronous itself . You don't need `async/await` to make it `asynchronous` . The `async/await` is added to make node.js code to run `synchronous` that means in sequence .

```
async function main(){
  await t1();
  await longProcess();
  await t2();
}
```

Means first `t1` will execute fully then `longProcess` , then `t2`.

If you write code like this

```
 function main(){
   t1();
   longProcess();
   t2();
}
```

It will execute as you want .

like `t1`, `longProcess` ,`t2` . No one will wait for each other to be completed .

Now you will say that why my result is same for both the method .
When you do Async/await and not do Async/await ?

The reason is that you functions are normal function they are not I/O event . So in this case your code will execute in sequence . To see as you want change your code like this.

```
function t1(){
  console.log(Date.now() + ' from t1(); ');
}

function longProcess(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10000000000) {
    i += 1;
  }

  funcGetTime();
  }, 0);
}

function t2(){
  console.log(Date.now() + ' from t2(); ');
}

function funcGetTime(){
  console.log(Date.now());
}

 function main(){
   t1();
   longProcess();
   t2();
}

main();
```

Now you got how it works.

Comment: Add why -1 ? . is any issue with answer

Comment: I didn't -1 you. So sorry for that though. However your example is also blocking, try running it. However the answer above yours is working correctly.

Comment: Checkout the first line of answer . This will make you understand node.js working better .

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!